# Dart stack trace all ends with 3/7/b/f (ARM architecture), while we know ARM/Thumb/Thumb(2) instructions are 2 or 4 bytes - How can that happen?

Tags: flutter, dart, compiler-construction, arm

I see that, Dart stack trace all ends with 3/7/b/f (ARM architecture), while we know ARM/Thumb/Thumb(2) instructions are 2 or 4 bytes.

example: https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/43274

```
Warning: This VM has been configured to produce stack traces that violate the Dart standard.
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
pid: 29278, tid: 29340, name 1.ui
isolate_dso_base: 6fe9d64000, vm_dso_base: 6fe9d64000
isolate_instructions: 6fe9d74000, vm_instructions: 6fe9d66000
    #00 abs 0000006fe9f4e87b virt 00000000001ea87b _kDartIsolateSnapshotInstructions+0x1da87b
    #01 abs 0000006fe9f4e4a3 virt 00000000001ea4a3 _kDartIsolateSnapshotInstructions+0x1da4a3
    #02 abs 0000006fe9d83ca3 virt 000000000001fca3 _kDartIsolateSnapshotInstructions+0xfca3
```

Thus, I wonder how could this happen? IMHO the ARM CPU will run the machine instructions (assembly) in the `.so` file in Android. But how can the CPU run it if all instructions do not align with 2/4 bytes?

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: Are you sure those are byte offsets?

Comment: @jamesdlin not sure. what else can it be? but seems that it is byte addr. https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/82ea8416ed2a22e40c5c67252cb37bebec3a57e8/runtime/docs/dwarf_stack_traces.md

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `lsb` is the "thumb bit" so to say.

You can switch between ARM and thumb mode with the instruction `bx` or `blx`.

These instructions scan the `lsb`, and if it's set, it will switch to thumb mode and to ARM mode if otherwise. Then branch to `address&~1`

The stack trace shows the return address of the caller functions, and that they are odd indicates that they are written/compiled in thumb mode.

Comment: Thanks so much! However, it seems that the `.so` file has instructions that are **4 bytes, not 2 bytes**. Could you please look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68523597 Showing that the objdump thinks every instruction is 4 bytes!

Comment: @ch271828n thumb2 instructions can be either 4 or 2 bytes long.