# What is inside the .so file generated by Flutter android?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, compiler-construction

I have read @mraleph 's [article](https://mrale.ph/dartvm/), but still cannot understand what is inside the `.so` file generated by Flutter android.

I have made an experiment: For my own app, I extract the .so from apk file (`mkdir -p 07260818_apk_unzip && unzip 07260818.apk -d 07260818_apk_unzip`), and dump out the instructions (`objdump -d ./07260818_apk_unzip/lib/armeabi-v7a/libapp.so > objdump.txt`). I also split debug info and do obfuscation, so I also dump out dwarf info (`drawfdump`).

I manually throw an Exception like

```
// debug_page.dart
              OutlinedButton(
                onPressed: () => throw Exception('hello exception (from simply onPressed) ${DateTime.now()}'),
                child: Text('normal'),
              ),
```

and see stack:

https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/5236035/126918360-67885121-c8bc-440a-93cb-38ce971b8bc1.png

Let me look at 0x5dfbdb:

dwarf -

```
0x001b3d78:   DW_TAG_subprogram
                DW_AT_abstract_origin   (0x000bf66f "__BodyState.build.<anonymous closure>")
                DW_AT_low_pc    (0x00000000005dfb18)
                DW_AT_high_pc   (0x00000000005dfbe0)

0x001b3d85:     DW_TAG_inlined_subroutine
                  DW_AT_abstract_origin (0x00006727 "new DateTime.now")
                  DW_AT_low_pc  (0x00000000005dfb54)
                  DW_AT_high_pc (0x00000000005dfb64)
                  DW_AT_call_file   ("package:yplusplus/pages/debug_page.dart")
                  DW_AT_call_line   (119)
                  DW_AT_call_column (102)

0x001b3d96:       DW_TAG_inlined_subroutine
                    DW_AT_abstract_origin   (0x0000673c "new DateTime._now")
                    DW_AT_low_pc    (0x00000000005dfb54)
                    DW_AT_high_pc   (0x00000000005dfb64)
                    DW_AT_call_file ("dart:core/date_time.dart")
                    DW_AT_call_line (209)
                    DW_AT_call_column   (25)

0x001b3da7:         NULL

0x001b3da8:       NULL

0x001b3da9:     DW_TAG_inlined_subroutine
                  DW_AT_abstract_origin (0x00005e4e "new Exception")
                  DW_AT_low_pc  (0x00000000005dfbbc)
                  DW_AT_high_pc (0x00000000005dfbc8)
                  DW_AT_call_file   ("package:yplusplus/pages/debug_page.dart")
                  DW_AT_call_line   (119)
                  DW_AT_call_column (40)

0x001b3dba:       NULL

0x001b3dbb:     NULL
```

instruction -

```
  5dfb10: f6 f5 0c eb                   bl  #3397592 <_kDartIsolateSnapshotInstructions+0x9112f0>
  5dfb14: 70 00 20 e1                   bkpt    #0
  5dfb18: 00 48 2d e9                   push    {r11, lr}
  5dfb1c: 00 b0 8d e2                   add r11, sp, #0
  5dfb20: 08 d0 4d e2                   sub sp, sp, #8
  5dfb24: 20 c0 9a e5                   ldr r12, [r10, #32]
  5dfb28: 0c 00 5d e1                   cmp sp, r12
  5dfb2c: 71 fa 0c 9b                   blls    #3402180 <_kDartIsolateSnapshotInstructions+0x9124f8>
  5dfb30: 68 10 9a e5                   ldr r1, [r10, #104]
  5dfb34: 04 20 a0 e3                   mov r2, #4
  5dfb38: 2c fa 0c eb                   bl  #3401904 <_kDartIsolateSnapshotInstructions+0x9123f0>
  5dfb3c: 04 00 0b e5                   str r0, [r11, #-4]
  5dfb40: 0b 20 80 e2                   add r2, r0, #11
  5dfb44: 19 ca 85 e2                   add r12, r5, #102400
  5dfb48: 6f c1 9c e5                   ldr r12, [r12, #367]
  5dfb4c: 00 c0 82 e5                   str r12, [r2]
  5dfb50: 71 ae e9 eb                   bl  #-5850684 <_kDartIsolateSnapshotInstructions+0x3f51c>
  5dfb54: 08 00 0b e5                   str r0, [r11, #-8]
  5dfb58: 70 c0 9a e5                   ldr r12, [r10, #112]
  5dfb5c: 0f c0 80 e5                   str r12, [r0, #15]
  5dfb60: 4e ae e9 eb                   bl  #-5850824 <_kDartIsolateSnapshotInstructions+0x3f4a0>
  5dfb64: c0 1f a0 e1                   asr r1, r0, #31
  5dfb68: c0 20 b0 e1                   asrs    r2, r0, #1
  5dfb6c: 01 00 00 3a                   blo #4 <_kDartIsolateSnapshotInstructions+0x5d3b78>
  5dfb70: 07 20 90 e5                   ldr r2, [r0, #7]
  5dfb74: 0b 10 90 e5                   ldr r1, [r0, #11]
  5dfb78: 08 00 1b e5                   ldr r0, [r11, #-8]
  5dfb7c: 07 20 80 e5                   str r2, [r0, #7]
  5dfb80: 0b 10 80 e5                   str r1, [r0, #11]
  5dfb84: 04 10 1b e5                   ldr r1, [r11, #-4]
  5dfb88: 0f 90 81 e2                   add r9, r1, #15
  5dfb8c: 00 00 89 e5                   str r0, [r9]
  5dfb90: 01 00 10 e3                   tst r0, #1
  5dfb94: 05 00 00 0a                   beq #20 <_kDartIsolateSnapshotInstructions+0x5d3bb0>
  5dfb98: 01 c0 51 e5                   ldrb    r12, [r1, #-1]
  5dfb9c: 01 e0 50 e5                   ldrb    lr, [r0, #-1]
  5dfba0: 2c c1 0e e0                   and r12, lr, r12, lsr #2
  5dfba4: 24 e0 9a e5                   ldr lr, [r10, #36]
  5dfba8: 0e 00 1c e1                   tst r12, lr
  5dfbac: d9 f5 0c 1b                   blne    #3397476 <_kDartIsolateSnapshotInstructions+0x911318>
  5dfbb0: 04 00 1b e5                   ldr r0, [r11, #-4]
  5dfbb4: 04 00 2d e5                   str r0, [sp, #-4]!
  5dfbb8: a8 b5 e8 eb                   bl  #-6105440 <_kDartIsolateSnapshotInstructions+0x1260>
  5dfbbc: 04 d0 8d e2                   add sp, sp, #4
  5dfbc0: 04 00 0b e5                   str r0, [r11, #-4]
  5dfbc4: 27 9e e9 eb                   bl  #-5867364 <_kDartIsolateSnapshotInstructions+0x3b468>
  5dfbc8: 00 10 a0 e1                   mov r1, r0
  5dfbcc: 04 00 1b e5                   ldr r0, [r11, #-4]
  5dfbd0: 03 00 81 e5                   str r0, [r1, #3]
  5dfbd4: 01 00 a0 e1                   mov r0, r1
  5dfbd8: c4 f5 0c eb                   bl  #3397392 <_kDartIsolateSnapshotInstructions+0x9112f0>
  5dfbdc: 70 00 20 e1                   bkpt    #0
  5dfbe0: 00 48 2d e9                   push    {r11, lr}
  5dfbe4: 00 b0 8d e2                   add r11, sp, #0
  5dfbe8: 10 d0 4d e2                   sub sp, sp, #16
```

However, it is quite strange. There is no instruction at 0x5dfbdb at all! (It is like in the middle of an instruction). In addition, does dart compiler generate .so file that is nothing but machine instructions? I do not see dart vm in the .so file.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: I think for a lot of your questions, you might be better off asking Dart team members directly on, say, Gitter: https://dart.dev/community#join-the-conversation

Comment: @jamesdlin actually i ask in github and no reply :/ I may try it, thanks!